# How to neglect value after 0 in decimal place VB.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I round up decimal variable to 4 places.

```
Dim a As Decimal = Math.Round(b, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

If value is `5400.40019`, I will get `5400.4002`.
But I don't want the value after `0` in decimal place.
For example, when the value is `5400.4001`, I only want `5400.4000`. If the value is `5400.0412`, all I want is `5400.0000`.

How can I?

Comment: Your examples indicate that you want to round to1 decimal place. Can you provide some more examples to make it clearer what you want?

Comment: Absolutely not. I wanna round 4 decimal place. But as I said, I don't want values behind 0 in decimal place, for example if value is '5400.1205', I want is '5400,1200'. But if value is '5400.1234', it is ok since there is no 0 in 4 decimal place. Sorry for grammar. English is not my mother language.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this method**

```
Public Function CustomFormater(b As Decimal) As Decimal
    Dim a As Decimal = Math.Round(b, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
    Dim pre As Int32 = Convert.ToInt32(a.ToString().Split(".")(1))
    Dim result As Int32 = If(pre Mod 1000 >= 500, pre + 1000 - pre Mod 1000, pre - pre Mod 1000)
    Dim output As Decimal = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(a.ToString().Split(".")(0) + "." + result.ToString()), 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
    Return output
End Function
```

you just need to call this method with you input decimal value.

**For example**

```
Dim b As Decimal = 5400.40019
MessageBox.Show("done" + CustomFormater(b).ToString())
```

Comment: @taymyinl Just as a fyi, you aren't supposed to add comments that basically just say "thanks" or "+1". The correct response for a useful answer is to upvote each useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that this is achievable without string manipulation. This should give you the result you are looking for. It rounds the decimal to 4 decimal places, converts it to a string then iterates each character of the string searching for the decimal place and then the first zero after the decimal place.

```
    Dim b As Decimal = 5400.40019D
    Dim a As Decimal = Math.Round(b, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
    Dim s As String = a.ToString
    Dim s2 As String = ""
    Dim bDecimalPointFound As Boolean
    Dim bZeroFound As Boolean

    For i As Int32 = 0 To s.Length - 1
        Dim sChar As String = s.Substring(i, 1)

        If bDecimalPointFound = True Then
            If sChar = "0" Then bZeroFound = True
            s2 &= If(bZeroFound = True, "0", sChar)
        Else
            s2 &= sChar
            bDecimalPointFound = (sChar = ".")
        End If
    Next

    Dim c As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(s2)
```